# why can gnome disks not format ext2 or ext3?

Tags: ext3, ext2, gnome-disks

Why does the GUI tool for formatting disks have no option to format with ext2 and ext3 filesystems? Why would a tool used for formatting exclude these filesystems? What is the rationale behind this annoyance?

Comment: It supports ext4.  Why do you need an ext2 or ext3 filesystem?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to ask the gnome developers to be sure, but the gnome project has a general policy of reducing complexity (and choice paralysis) by eliminating choices.  My guess is that the reasoning is something like this:

**Most** people don't need (and will **never** need) to format a disk with ext2 or ext3, so those choices aren't needed in the gnome tool.

Those who do want ancient disk formats for some reason can be presumed to know enough to format it themselves with `mkfs`, or a more "full-featured" GUI app like `gparted`.

Comment: BTW, many will argue that Gnome goes too far with that policy, but that's a different issue.   A very subjective issue, and the only real answer to it is "Use gnome if it works for you. Use something else if it doesn't".   Personally, I use `xfce` and do my disk-formatting (and almost everything else) from the command line.